How to execute a TS that was designed for solana Playground, locally. To launch on mainnet
I have a TypeScript script that was initially created to run in the Solana Playground, and I would like to execute it locally on my pc, since playground only allows devnet. I only want to update the metadata, but i cant find any specific script that only updates metadata. I already succesfully changed the script to search for my keypair locally, but i still get an error.
import {
  Connection,
  Keypair,
  SystemProgram,
  Transaction,
  clusterApiUrl,
  sendAndConfirmTransaction,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
import {
  ExtensionType,
  TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
  createInitializeMintInstruction,
  getMintLen,
  createInitializeMetadataPointerInstruction,
  getMint,
  getMetadataPointerState,
  getTokenMetadata,
  TYPE_SIZE,
  LENGTH_SIZE,
} from "@solana/spl-token";
import {
  createInitializeInstruction,
  createUpdateFieldInstruction,
  createRemoveKeyInstruction,
  pack,
  TokenMetadata,
} from "@solana/spl-token-metadata";

import { readFileSync } from "fs";

// Read the secret key from keypair.json
const secretKeyString = readFileSync("C:\Users\reinn\Desktop\DANKDOLLAR FINAL\Coding(clispl)\EAe3oD58wsz3WcuaxdYARt6o32uE82BtL3B5sRz7nDh6.json", "utf8");

// Parse the secret key string into a Uint8Array
const secretKey = Uint8Array.from(JSON.parse(secretKeyString));

// Create a keypair from the secret key
const keypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKey);

// Playground wallet
const payer = keypair;

// Connection to devnet cluster
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");

// Transaction to send
let transaction: Transaction;
// Transaction signature returned from sent transaction
let transactionSignature: string;

// Generate new keypair for Mint Account
const mintKeypair = Keypair.generate();
// Address for Mint Account
const mint = mintKeypair.publicKey;
// Decimals for Mint Account
const decimals = 2;
// Authority that can mint new tokens
const mintAuthority = keypair.publicKey;
// Authority that can update token metadata
const updateAuthority = keypair.publicKey;

// Metadata to store in Mint Account
const metaData: TokenMetadata = {
  updateAuthority: updateAuthority,
  mint: mint,
  name: "OPOS",
  symbol: "OPOS",
  uri: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solana-developers/opos-asset/main/assets/DeveloperPortal/metadata.json",
  additionalMetadata: [["description", "Only Possible On Solana"]],
};

// Size of MetadataExtension 2 bytes for type, 2 bytes for length
const metadataExtension = TYPE_SIZE + LENGTH_SIZE;
// Size of metadata
const metadataLen = pack(metaData).length;

// Size of Mint Account with extension
const mintLen = getMintLen([ExtensionType.MetadataPointer]);

// Minimum lamports required for Mint Account
const lamports = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(
  mintLen + metadataExtension + metadataLen
);

// Instruction to invoke System Program to create new account
const createAccountInstruction = SystemProgram.createAccount({
  fromPubkey: payer.publicKey, // Account that will transfer lamports to created account
  newAccountPubkey: mint, // Address of the account to create
  space: mintLen, // Amount of bytes to allocate to the created account
  lamports, // Amount of lamports transferred to created account
  programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, // Program assigned as owner of created account
});

// Instruction to initialize the MetadataPointer Extension
const initializeMetadataPointerInstruction =
  createInitializeMetadataPointerInstruction(
    mint, // Mint Account address
    updateAuthority, // Authority that can set the metadata address
    mint, // Account address that holds the metadata
    TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
  );

// Instruction to initialize Mint Account data
const initializeMintInstruction = createInitializeMintInstruction(
  mint, // Mint Account Address
  decimals, // Decimals of Mint
  mintAuthority, // Designated Mint Authority
  null, // Optional Freeze Authority
  TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID // Token Extension Program ID
);

// Instruction to initialize Metadata Account data
const initializeMetadataInstruction = createInitializeInstruction({
  programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, // Token Extension Program as Metadata Program
  metadata: mint, // Account address that holds the metadata
  updateAuthority: updateAuthority, // Authority that can update the metadata
  mint: mint, // Mint Account address
  mintAuthority: mintAuthority, // Designated Mint Authority
  name: metaData.name,
  symbol: metaData.symbol,
  uri: metaData.uri,
});

// Instruction to update metadata, adding custom field
const updateFieldInstruction = createUpdateFieldInstruction({
  programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, // Token Extension Program as Metadata Program
  metadata: mint, // Account address that holds the metadata
  updateAuthority: updateAuthority, // Authority that can update the metadata
  field: metaData.additionalMetadata[0][0], // key
  value: metaData.additionalMetadata[0][1], // value
});

// Add instructions to new transaction
transaction = new Transaction().add(
  createAccountInstruction,
  initializeMetadataPointerInstruction,
  initializeMintInstruction,
  initializeMetadataInstruction,
  updateFieldInstruction
);

// Send transaction
transactionSignature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
  connection,
  transaction,
  [payer, mintKeypair] // Signers
);

console.log(
  "\nCreate Mint Account:",
  `https://solana.fm/tx/${transactionSignature}?cluster=devnet-solana`
);

// Retrieve mint information
const mintInfo = await getMint(
  connection,
  mint,
  "confirmed",
  TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID
);

// Retrieve and log the metadata pointer state
const metadataPointer = getMetadataPointerState(mintInfo);
console.log("\nMetadata Pointer:", JSON.stringify(metadataPointer, null, 2));

// Retrieve and log the metadata state
const metadata = await getTokenMetadata(
  connection,
  mint // Mint Account address
);
console.log("\nMetadata:", JSON.stringify(metadata, null, 2));

// Instruction to remove a key from the metadata
const removeKeyInstruction = createRemoveKeyInstruction({
  programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, // Token Extension Program as Metadata Program
  metadata: mint, // Address of the metadata
  updateAuthority: updateAuthority, // Authority that can update the metadata
  key: metaData.additionalMetadata[0][0], // Key to remove from the metadata
  idempotent: true, // If the idempotent flag is set to true, then the instruction will not error if the key does not exist
});

// Add instruction to new transaction
transaction = new Transaction().add(removeKeyInstruction);

// Send transaction
transactionSignature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
  connection,
  transaction,
  [payer]
);

console.log(
  "\nRemove Additional Metadata Field:",
  `https://solana.fm/tx/${transactionSignature}?cluster=devnet-solana`
);

// Retrieve and log the metadata state
const updatedMetadata = await getTokenMetadata(
  connection,
  mint // Mint Account address
);
console.log("\nUpdated Metadata:", JSON.stringify(updatedMetadata, null, 2));

console.log(
  "\nMint Account:",
  `https://solana.fm/address/${mint}?cluster=devnet-solana`
);


I it possible to change this script so that it uses a locally stored keypair instead of the "PG" playground reference term?
I tried to change the following:
import { readFileSync } from "fs";
// Read the secret key from keypair.json
const secretKeyString = readFileSync("path/to/keypair.json", "utf8");
// Parse the secret key string into a Uint8Array
const secretKey = Uint8Array.from(JSON.parse(secretKeyString));
// Create a keypair from the secret key
const keypair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKey);
but i still get this error:
C:\Users\newmetadata.ts:47
const lamports = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(mintLen + metadataExtension + metadataLen);
                 ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:77:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1288:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1340:27)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\Users\private\index.ts:1618:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (C:\Users\reinn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1621:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at phase4 (C:\Users\bin.ts:649:14)


The simplest way to get rid of this error is to wrap your code (except imports at the top) in an async function and call it immediately:
async function main () {
    // ... your code here
}
main();

